# SQL Join with CASE and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables - one for shipping rates, one for products and one for exceptions to shipping rate for particular products. Shipping is charged as follows:
Each product has a shipping price, but this price can be overridden by an exception. If no exception exists for a product, the default rate is used for the shipping rate selected by the user.
[alt text http://mi6.nu/sqljoin.png](http://mi6.nu/sqljoin.png)
I'm trying to join these tables so that if an exception exists, that price is selected, otherwise, the default price is selected but I'm having problems with the join. I need to query by product ID, and I have (line 2 is for debugging)

```
SELECT r.ID AS ShippingRateID, r.Name, 
e.*, r.*
FROM shipping r LEFT JOIN shippingexceptions e ON r.ID = e.ShippingRateID
WHERE e.ProductID = 48
```

And I need returned:

```
1   Uk and Northern Ireland 1
2   EU Eire...      10
3   US and Canada       2.16
4   Rest of world       2.44
```

So if an exception exists, the exception price is used, otherwise the default price is used. I'm planning to use a CASE statement, but I need to return the data first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I notice is that you have a predicate condition on table e, which is on the "outer" side of an outer join.  This will immediately turn the join into an Inner join, as the rows that would ordinarilly have been produced where there is a record on the inner side but no record on the outer side, would have all nulls in the columns from the outer table by the time the where clause predicate (WHERE e.ProductID = 48) is executed.

You need to put this predicate in the join conditions instead.
   like this:

```
 SELECT r.ID AS ShippingRateID, r.Name, e.*, r.*
 FROM shipping r 
    LEFT JOIN  shippingexceptions e 
        ON r.ID = e.ShippingRateID
             And e.ProductID = 48
```

Next, as Joels answer recommended, for a simple expression, although a case would work, you don't need a case statement, Coalesce will suffice:

```
 SELECT r.ID AS ShippingRateID, r.Name, 
     Coalesce(e.rate, defaultrate) as Rate,
     e.*, r.*
 FROM shipping r 
    LEFT JOIN  shippingexceptions e 
        ON r.ID = e.ShippingRateID
             And e.ProductID = 48
```

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of why e.ProductId belongs on the join.

Comment: Thanks, I understand wwhy this works. I actually had no idea you could JOIN with AND. Something you learn as you go along I think. :)

Answer (score 8):

Why not use a coalesce

```
SELECT r.ID AS ShippingRateID, r.Name, coalesce(e.cost, r.defaultprice)
FROM shipping r LEFT JOIN shippingexceptions e ON r.ID = e.ShippingRateID
WHERE e.ProductID = 48
```

This way, if e.rate is null, r.rate is used.

You also should put your e.ProductId on the join so it doesn't force you to select only products with exceptions

```
SELECT r.ID AS ShippingRateID, r.Name, coalesce(e.cost, r.defaultprice)
FROM shipping r LEFT JOIN shippingexceptions e ON r.ID = e.ShippingRateID and e.ProductID = 48
```

Comment: One "l" in coalesce - not two.  Otherwise a great response, and a very good point about the WHERE clause; I didn't notice that the OP had done that.

Comment: Heh, thanks. I'm a programmer, not an English major. I usually rely on syntax checkers and compilers for that stuff. ;)

Comment: You can also use ISNULL, I'm not sure if there is any performance benefit vs COALESCE if you only have two expressions to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are on MSSQL, COALESCE function would help. It returns first not-null.

It is, 
`select COALESCE(shippingexceptions.Rate, shipping.Rate )`

Do the same thing with case.. when :

```
Select Case when shippingexceptions.Rate is not null THEN shippingexceptions.Rate
ELSE shipping.Rate
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 cost
        FROM    shippingexceptions se
        WHERE   se.ShippingRateID = r.id
                AND se.ProductID = 48
        ), DefaultPrice
        ) AS price
FROM    shipping r
```

, or in `SQL Server 2005+`:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(cost, DefaultPrice) AS price
FROM    shipping r
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 cost
        FROM    shippingexceptions
        WHERE   ShippingRateID = r.id
                AND ProductID = 48
        ) se
```